# factorialize a number using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion and found the below as the answer to a freecodecamp recursion exercise to factorialize a number. It's correct but I don't understand how it runs.

- -If the 'return 1' exits the function, then shouldn't the output be 1?
- -The desired pattern if 10x9x8x7 etc. But if it's calling itself each time doesn't this follow the pattern 10x9, 9x8, 8x7 etc?

Sorry if this isn't an appropriate question, first time using.

```
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0) { return 1; }
  return num * factorialize(num-1);
}

factorialize(5);
>120
```

Comment: 1 returns 1, 2 returns 2*(1), 3 returns 3*(2*(1)), etc. (I'm using parentheses to symbolize a call to the function within the function itself)

Comment: The last call that has `return 1` is not returned as the result of the first call to `factorialize`. It is merely returned as the result of the previous call to `factorialize(num-1)` which is then multiplied by the corresponding `num` and returned as the result of the previous `factorialize(num-1)` which is multiplied by the corresponding `num` ... and so on and so forth untill the we reach the first call to `factorialize`. By that time all the factorial is already calculated.

Answer (score 5):

Since the individual results of a recursive function are accumulated, one can imagine this process in the following way:

1. call factorialize(5);
2. first recursion step returns -> 5 * factorialize(4)

   > current value: 5 * factorialize(4)
3. second recursion step returns -> 4 * factorialize(3)

   > current value: 5 * 4 * factorialize(3)
4. third recursion step returns -> 3 * factorialize(2)

   > current value: 5 * 4 * 3 * factorialize(2)
5. fourth recursion step returns -> 2 * factorialize(1)

   > current value: 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorialize(1)
6. sixth recursion step returns -> 1 * factorialize(0)

   > current value: 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorialize(0)
7. seventh (last) recursion step returns -> 1

   > current value: 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1

This results in 120.

```
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0) { return 1; }      // 7th step
  return num * factorialize(num-1); // 1st to 6th step
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing the function iteratively may help clarify matters; each step in the loop is equivalent to one recursive call.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  let factorial = 1; // base case, equivalent to fact(0)

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) { // multiply for each number from 1 to n
    factorial *= i;
  }

  return factorial;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

The recursive function works the same way. `fact(n)` is the original call, but to compute `fact(n)`, it must first compute the factorial of `n - 1`. `fact(n - 1)` cannot be computed without `fact(n - 2)`. Each function is pushed onto the call stack, waiting for functions above it to resolve. Eventually `fact(0)` will be called, and this we know to be `1` based on the [recursive definition of factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition). `fact(0)` is called the *base case* and will not make any recursive calls. Without the base case, `n` gets smaller and smaller until the stack runs out of space, crashing the program.

Armed with information from the base case, `fact(1)` can now compute `1 * 1` and pass the result, `1`, to its calling function, `fact(2)`. `fact(2)` computes `2 * 1` and passes the result to `fact(3)`, which computes `3 * 2` and passes the result to `fact(4)`, which computes `4 * 6` and passes the result to `fact(5)`, which computes `5 * 24` and returns the final result of `120`.

If that still doesn't make sense, toss in a `console.log()` to view each step along the way:

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  if (num === 0) { // base case 
    console.log("fact(0) returning 1");
    return 1; 
  }

  // recursive case
  const result = num * factorialize(num - 1);
  console.log("fact(" + num + ") returning " + result);
  return result;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```